# JAR file not finding embedded resource -- issue with relative path?

Tags: java, jar, embedded-resource

I have a JAR file which I have created manually via this command *(line-wrapped to read easily)*:

```
jar -cfm app_standalone.jar manifest.txt 
application/client/*.class
application/data/*.class  
application/startup/*.class 
*.txt
```

The manifest looks like this:

```
Main-Class: application.startup.StartFrame
```

I run this command in the directory outside `/application/`.  The directory structure of the resulting JAR looks like this:

```
[ROOT_DIR_OF_JAR]/type1.txt
[ROOT_DIR_OF_JAR]/type2.txt
[ROOT_DIR_OF_JAR]/type3.txt
[ROOT_DIR_OF_JAR]/application
[ROOT_DIR_OF_JAR]/application/client/example.class
[ROOT_DIR_OF_JAR]/application/data/another.class
[ROOT_DIR_OF_JAR]/application/startup/run_me.class
```

When I run the JAR file, it executes fine, but **only** if it resides in the same directory as the `.txt` files, which it is apparently referencing.  The code that points to those `.txt` files resides in `/application/client/` :

```java
package application.client;
String typeName = "type2";  // could be type1 or type3
InputStream is = modelViewer.modelEnv.openFile(typeName + ".txt");
// ===============================================================
package application.startup;
public InputStream openFile(String name) {
    File f;
    FileInputStream is = null;
    String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    f = new File(dir, name);
    is = new FileInputStream(f);
    return is;
}
```

I tried creating the JAR with the `.txt` "resource" files in the `/client/` directory, with no success.  I have also tried changing the path in the code, as suggested by other answers to similar questions.  I'm guessing that it's some sort of issue with using a relative path.  What can I do to make these files referenced properly **within** the JAR, so the application can be run stand-alone?

Comment: What is the value of `typeName`?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `typeName` is just a string that corresponds to one of the `.txt` filenames -- `type1`, `type2`, `type3`.  Apologies, I thought that was self-evident.

Comment: *"I thought that was self-evident."*  An SSCCE is 'self evident'.  Where is yours?

Comment: @RC. -- That works.  I thought I'd tried that but it turns out I hadn't created the JAR file properly that time.  >.<

Comment: Without knowing what openFile() does, it's hard to explain why it's right or wrong.

Comment: @JBNizet -- I added the relevant code.  It's an `InputStream` in an interface.

Comment: What we need is the **implementation** of this method.

Comment: @JBNizet -- Yeah, I added it.  >.<  Sorry, this is not my code, it's from a defunct project.  I think I see what the problem is now, actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method doesn't load files from the classpath, but from the current directory in the file system. That's what the problem is.

To load a resource from the classpath, `Class.getResourceAsStream()` (or `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`) must be used.

Comment: Pretty obvious once I finally looked at the implementation of the `openFile()` method -- thanks for pointing me in this direction!